# After Running 'rail server' in ruby and I got this Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:\test_install>rails server
C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:10:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/test_install/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RubySdk/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you using zip gem ? Have you run 'bundle install' after adding gems to gem file ?

Comment: I found this [Issue](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/90) on GitHub

Comment: No I was trying to install ruby rails on my pc in cmd.